# Old list is changing after copying to the new one

Tags: python, list, copy

I want to save a copy of my old list. But whatever I do it is changing. My old list `output` contains of dictionaries. `output_work` is a copy. Example of output before actions:

[image]

What I was doing:

```
output_work = output.copy()
```

and

```
output_work = [i for i in output]
```

and

```
output_work = list(output)
```

and

```
import copy
output_work = copy.copy(output)
```

and

```
output_work = []
output_work.extend(output)
```

After some actions with `output_work` the result is next

[image]

What can I do to keep original `output`?

Comment: You need to use `copy.deepcopy()`. You're copying the list, but both copies have references to the same dictionaries.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Or, you can just "deepcopy" manually, in this case, `[d.copy() for d in output]`. Basically, you need to copy the dicts *inside* the list as well, otherwise `list.copy` doesn't do that (and equivalent methods). They are shallow copies